# Reduce cpu cores on Unix system with ant

Tags: unix, ant, jenkins, hudson, cpu

I'm trying dynamically to reduce cpu cores of a unix system during it's working. All this must happen using an ant script and jenkins.

My code is:

```
    '<exec executable="sh" os="Linux" spawn="no">
            <arg line="-c echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online" />
    </exec>'
```

But on jenkins console all i got is just [exec] with no action and

```
[exec] /bin/echo: /bin/echo: cannot execute binary file
[exec] Result: 126
```

Anyone have an idea what actually I should pass to the arg line ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   '<exec executable="sh" os="Linux" spawn="no">
            <arg line="-c 'echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online'" />
    </exec>'
```

I am assuming you are able execute the command successfully from the command line.  Add some single tics. -c requires a quote enclosed string.